# Return on Appropriate Spot

Tags: java, return

Isn't this supposed to return correct value? as it specifically defines `int[] temp`? However, it says `temp` is not resolved. so I had to put another return `temp` inside `if` and change the last `return` inside `else` statement so there were two returns as a result. If I set values inside if and else, couldn't I return it outside?

```
public int[] maxEnd3(int[] nums) {

    if (nums[0] > nums[2]) {
        int[] temp = {nums[0],nums[0],nums[0]};
    }
    else {
        int[] temp= {nums[2],nums[2],nums[2]};
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare temp in the correct scope.
Try this:

```
public int[] maxEnd3(int[] nums) {
    int []temp = new int[3];
    if (nums[0] > nums[2]) {
        temp[0] = nums[0];
        temp[1] = nums[0];
        temp[2] = nums[0];
    }
    else {
        temp[0] = nums[2];
        temp[1] = nums[2];
        temp[2] = nums[2];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Or this:

```
public int[] maxEnd3(int[] nums) {
    int []temp;
    if (nums[0] > nums[2]) {
        temp = new int[]{nums[0],nums[0],nums[0]};
    }
    else {
        temp = new int[]{nums[2],nums[2],nums[2]};
    }
    return temp;
}
```

When you declare it inside the if statement, it's only valid between the declaration line and the closing brace.